# How can I add an overlayItem object to an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, itemizedoverlay

Can you tell me please how I can add an overlayItem object to an array?
I tried in this way:

```
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[1])),(int)(Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[0])));
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[1]) + "", Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[0]) +"");
    List<OverlayItem> arrItem[] = overlayItem;
```

But I got an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from OverlayItem to List[]

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10061636/1289716

Comment: what OverlayItem  type ? past the code of this class .

Comment: OverlayItem provided by google library: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem

Comment: @gtumca-MAC Not sure how this is related to the specific question...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing arrays and lists. If you don't have to use an array, using a list is easier, in which case you probably meant to write:

```
List<OverlayItem> itemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem> (); // create an empty list
itemList.add(overlayItem); // add you item to the list
```

If you want to use an array you would write it like this - but you need to manage the size of the array yourself (which is why using a list as above is easier):

```
OverlayItem[] itemArray = new OverlayItem[10]; //if you only need to insert 10 items
itemArray[0] = overlayItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is right because look at the decleartion: `OverlayItem overlayItem` and `List<OverlayItem> arrItem[]`.
So if you `arrItem[] = overlayItem` you implicit claim `List<OverlayItem> = OverlayItem`. :)
(I'm not sure but I think it's even "worse" with the `[]` at the end of variable's name. I think the brackets are reserved for arrays thus `List<OverlayItem> arrItem[]` results in an *Array* of *Lists* o.O)

You want to create a new List of OverlayItems and thenn add the item to this list. I'm not sure if you can instantiate `List` directly so I use `ArrayList`:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[1])),(int)(Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[0])));
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[1]) + "", Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[0]) +"");
    ArrayList<OverlayItem> arrItem = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    arrItem.add(overlayItem);
```