# Replace marker with another one

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

IN my android map application I am trying to replace marker on touch event.This is my overlay item class and my default marker defined in main class .

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( null, R.drawable.image_pin);//Replace with this marker

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> myOverlaysNormal ;



Context mContext;


public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    myOverlaysNormal = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    populate();

}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay){
    myOverlaysNormal.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return myOverlaysNormal.get(i);
}
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {

myOverlaysNormal.get(index).getPoint();


return true;
}

// Removes overlay item i
public void removeItem(int i){
    myOverlaysNormal.remove(i);

    populate();
}

// Returns present number of items in list
@Override
public int size() {
    return myOverlaysNormal.size();
}


public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem) {
    myOverlaysNormal.add(overlayItem);
    populate();
}



}
```

How can I replace touched marker with another marker(R.Drawable.image_pin)..
**OR** How can I expand the marker default marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multi-way to do it i hope i can help in your code but u should make good search and good read.

here some link will help u :

[First Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058666/adding-a-custom-marker-to-map-android)

[2 example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428730/creating-custom-overlay-on-the-map)